# mathGl / MinGW undefined reference Netbeans IDE

Tags: c++, netbeans, mingw, mathgl

I'm trying to compile the below code :

```
#include <cstdlib>
#define HAVE_STRUCT_TIMESPEC
#include <mgl2/mgl.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   mglGraph gr;
   gr.FPlot("sin(pi*x)");
   gr.WriteFrame("test.png");
   return 0;
}
```

I'm using Netbeans IDE , Win 10 64x .... but keep getting this error :

Appreciate your help.

cd 'C:\Users\SAQERpc\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Plotting'
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\make.exe -f Makefile CONF=Debug
"/C/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make.exe[1]: Entering directory `/c/Users/SAQERpc/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Plotting'
"/C/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/plotting.exe
make.exe[2]: Entering directory`/c/Users/SAQERpc/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Plotting'
mkdir -p build/Debug/MinGW-Windows
rm -f "build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o.d"
g++    -c -g -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o.d" -o build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o main.cpp
mkdir -p dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows
g++     -o dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/plotting build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o  -lmgl
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o: In function `ZN8mglGraphC1Eiii':
c:/mingw/include/mgl2/mgl.h:39: undefined reference to`_imp___ZTV8mglGraph'
c:/mingw/include/mgl2/mgl.h:42: undefined reference to `_imp__mgl_create_graph_gl'
c:/mingw/include/mgl2/mgl.h:48: undefined reference to`_imp__mgl_create_graph'
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o: In function `ZN8mglGraphD1Ev':
c:/mingw/include/mgl2/mgl.h:53: undefined reference to`_imp___ZTV8mglGraph'
c:/mingw/include/mgl2/mgl.h:53: undefined reference to `_imp__mgl_use_graph'
c:/mingw/include/mgl2/mgl.h:53: undefined reference to`_imp__mgl_delete_graph'
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o: In function `ZN8mglGraph11SetFontSizeEd':
c:/mingw/include/mgl2/mgl.h:122: undefined reference to`_imp__mgl_set_font_size'
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o: In function `ZN8mglGraph10WriteFrameEPKcS1_':
c:/mingw/include/mgl2/mgl.h:399: undefined reference to`_imp__mgl_write_frame'
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o: In function `ZN8mglGraph5FPlotEPKcS1_S1_':
c:/mingw/include/mgl2/mgl.h:1973: undefined reference to`_imp__mgl_fplot'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make.exe[2]: *** [dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/plotting.exe] Error 1
make.exe[2]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/SAQERpc/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Plotting'
make.exe[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make.exe[1]: Leaving directory`/c/Users/SAQERpc/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Plotting'
make.exe": *** [.build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 2s)

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell linker a library name, containing all the mathGL functions. In Netbeans 8.2 you can do that in the following way (I'm assuming your project is "C/C++ Application"):

- Open your project properties
- Click "Linker" in the left pane
- Find "Libraries" line and click button with "..." on its right side
- Click "Add option..." in the right pane
- Select "Other Option" and type "-lmgl"
- Click "Ok"
- Rebuild your project

This final popup window, titled "Select Option", should look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this too

```
Open your project properties
Click "Linker" in the left pane
Find "Libraries" line and click button with "..." on its right side
Click "Add option..." in the right pane
Select "Other Option" and type "-lodbc"
Click "Ok"
Rebuild your project
```